# Issue in column formatting in SharePoint JSON with If statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a simple JSON formatting code for a column in SharePoint in order to redirect to the appropriate target depending on the content of the record.

Here is the code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
        "href": "=IF(LEFT(@currentField,3)=='INC', 'https://domain.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=incident.do?sysparm_query=number=' + @currentField, IF(LEFT(@currentField,3)=='PRB', 'https://domain.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=problem.do?sysparm_query=number=' + @currentField, 'https://domain.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/CCE/issues/' + @currentField))",
"target": "_blank"
  }
}
```

The format is accepted by SharePoint, but the output is blank. So I'm a bit stunned.

And the simple code is working like a charm:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://domain.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=incident.do?sysparm_query=number='+ @currentField"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Try JSON given in my answer below. Let me know if it works for you or if you face any issues while using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT()` function is from SharePoint calculated column formulas which is not supported in SharePoint JSON formatting.

Use below JSON column formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=if(substring(@currentField,0,3)=='INC', 'https://domain.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=incident.do?sysparm_query=number=' + @currentField, if(substring(@currentField,0,3)=='PRB', 'https://domain.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=problem.do?sysparm_query=number=' + @currentField, 'https://domain.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/CCE/issues/' + @currentField))",
    "target": "_blank"
  }
}
```

You can also refer column values in JSON in the format `[$MyColumnName]` instead of `@currentField`. Where `MyColumnName`  is the internal name of your SharePoint list column.

You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: You can use either `substring` or `startsWith` operator for such requirements.

Comment: Waouh. you're awesome. SO powerful § it works like a charm. Thank you so much !

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it worked for you! Keep using this platform to ask any questions related to SharePoint.